# MVC Core, how to access Current Username/Email logged in on another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

needed help here.
Does anyone know how to access Username/Email logged in on another controller?
What I mean is that let's say I am in a View called "StudentDetails" and controller "Student", how to retrieve the current user information logged in such as their username or email?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you use ASP.NET Identity use UserManager<ApplicationUser>.GetUser(this.User)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to inject an instance of UserManager in your controller constructor.

```
public class MyController{

    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    public MyController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager){
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, and how to actually access the email and username?

Comment: @Lisa userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName), for example. Here you have the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: ApplicationUser user = UserManager<ApplicationUser>.GetUser(this.User); then user.Name or user.Email

Comment: var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);